# What's these files in PSP?

Tags: psp, system-mods

I've got a PSP 3000, with custom firmware 5.03-Prome3. I found these files in my PSP root directory and wonder what's their usage?

- `en_recovery.txt`
- `usersystemlib620.prx`

Comment: This is unofficial/modded firmware for the PSP.  The question is allowed, as per this thread on meta, and I think it should probably be tagged 'mods' although the description for 'mods' doesn't include console modifications at this point.  see: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/258/whats-the-official-stance-on-hacked-modded-consoles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`en_recovery.txt` is the text for a custom firmware's recovery menu; `usersystemlib620.prx` seems to be related to using CFW to play *Kingdom Hearts: Birth By Sleep*.

They may be safe to delete if you don't run CFW, but as always, keep a backup of your files handy just in case.